# Online tutorial on lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Any online tutorial on lisp which can teach the basics (loop, condition and etc) of this language in a short time?

Comment: What variant? Scheme? Common Lisp?

Answer (score 6):

Common Lisp tutorial on Wikibooks, 
for beginners, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Common_Lisp/First_steps/Beginner_tutorial
, bit more advanced, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Common_Lisp/First_steps/Experienced_tutorial

Not a tutorial but rather a full book (but good and straight forward): Practical Common Lisp,  http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/

Steve Yegge's Emergency Elisp is not about Common Lisp, but I still find it quite good to get at feeling for the Lisp family of languages:
http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/01/emergency-elisp.html

Answer (score 2):

If you can make it through it (I wasn't able to the first time I read it), reading Paul Graham's *[The Roots of Lisp](http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/paulgraham/jmc.ps)* gives a nice overview of the very basics of the language, and how to implement it in itself, with only a few primitives.

*[On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html)* is another, oft-recomended and not too out of date book, again by Paul Graham, that will definitely teach you what you want to know. It's online, for free.

Personally, though, I'd recommend [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) to you over CL. It's got a fast-growing, welcoming, smart community making cool things. Not only that, but you've got access to everything that Java does, and you're running on the JVM (it's portable and *damn* fast).

Good luck!

Comment: I have seen some of the Clojure community, and I don't think they're that fat-growing; some of them are rather trim.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/ is a good start - read up to chapter 3. Chapter 3 really gets you the feel. The rest of the book is good too, but I recommend reading .... http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/ next. From there, you should read .... http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/

I chose these in order of importance and difficulty. SL being the easiest and most important, then Gentle, then PCL